# Problem with amcl_demo.launch and depth data from camera/depth/image

Tags: openni, turtlebot, amcl-demo.launch, camera, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm having some troubles using the amcl_demo.launch, because i need to get the depth information from the **camera/depth/image** which the openni.launch initializes (and is initialized by **amcl_demo.launch**). But using the amcl_demo.launch the only topic i can acess to get this depth data is **camera/depth/image_raw**, but nothing happens in it apparently (i checked using *image_view*).

I've checked at this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/190483/depth-image-on-amcl_demo/) and followed the instructions by changing that parameters in amcl_demo.launch but i still can't make this work.

Using the **openni.launch**, it's possible to get the depth information perfectly from the topic **/camera/depth/image**. To get the depth data as well as i did from /camera/depth/image (from another topic like /camera/depth_registered/image_raw), do i need to convert the image before using ?

My code calculates the distance from an object, and with the /camera/depth/image launched by openni.launch it's possible to calculate as follow (not exactly this, i just copied the important parts):

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr Dest;
Dest = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img);
ROI = Dest->image(cv::Rect(rect));
cv::Scalar average = cv::mean(ROI.at<float>());
```

I'd like to know how can i calculate the distance from the topic /camera/depth/image_raw, or another one that provides the depth information. (changing as less as possible this code)

**EDIT**: With depth_registration activated in amcl_demo.launch, the topics **/camera/depth_registered/image_raw** and  **/camera/depth_registered/image** doesn't publish data, the only one publishing is **/camera/depth/image_raw** but its type does not follow the one i'm using, i've tried to convert using this: `Dest = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img,sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1);` but i got 0 meters distance.
What am i doing wrong?

*Thanks in advance!*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207615/problem-with-amcl_demo.launch-and-depth-data-from-camera/depth/image/) by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess i found the solution:

Using the **/camera/depth_registered/image_raw** and setting depth_registration true in **amcl_demo.launch**, my CallBack function is converting the image to a 32-bit float type as follow: `Dest = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(img,sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);` .

The difference between this topic and that **/camera/depth/image** is that this one gives me the distance in mm, and the other one provides the distance in m.

---

Originally posted by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) with karma: 74 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0